# How to pass values from shell to plsql block

Tags: linux, shell, plsql, sqlplus

I am creating a new user in ebs as:

```
user_name=$(echo $1 | cut -d':' -f2)
password=$(echo $2 | cut -d':' -f2)

sqlplus -s /NOLOG << EOF
connect apps/apps@<IP>:1521/VIS

declare
    v_user_name varchar2(30):=$user_name;
    v_password varchar2(30):=$password;
begin
    fnd_user_pkg.createuser (
        x_user_name => v_user_name,
        x_owner => null,
        x_unencrypted_password => v_password,
        x_session_number => null,
        x_start_date => sysdate,
        x_end_date => null,
        x_email_address => null
    );

    commit;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('User:'||v_user_name||'Created Successfully');

exception
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Unable to create User due to'||SQLCODE||'
        '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100));

        rollback;
 end;
/

exit
EOF
```

I'm getting error in the assignment line as follows.

> v_password varchar2(30):= DEMO@123;
>                                  *
>
> ERROR at line 3:
>
> ORA-06550: line 3, column 32:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "123" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> @
>
> The symbol " was inserted before "123" to continue.
>
> And the same error for when assigning v_user_name the value $user_name;

How do I pass the values from shell to pl/sql block?

Comment: did you try `v_user_name varchar2(30):='$user_name';` or `v_user_name varchar2(30):='&user_name';`

Comment: Yes, I tried v_user_name varchar2(30):='$user_name';. Since I'm running my code in an environment where I cannot take user input, I'm unable to use v_user_name varchar2(30):='&user_name';

Comment: I also tried v_user_name varchar2(30):="$user_name"; but no luck

Comment: the problem is that the `@` needs to be escaped as special character in the password.

Comment: btw `sqlcode` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: After substitution, `v_user_name varchar2(30):=$user_name;` will become something like `v_user_name varchar2(30):=fredjones92;` What happens exactly when you add the missing single quotes? (Not just 'no luck' please.)